# Change Community Page Name for Custom Object Page

Tags: custom-object, lightning-community

I have a Community Object Page that has the page name of the original custom object I created.  Since then, I have changed the custom object's name to something more pertinent.  I can't figure out how to change the page name.  While the below image isn't my exact scenario, it shows an example of what I am trying to change.  In this example, I want to change the text in the Name field to match the new name I assigned to my custom object.  It is grayed out.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like deleting the object page and recreating it works.